# Passing data from cellforRowatIndexPath to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to pass in the String "random text" to equal the property imageURL that is located inside of the custom Cell UserCell from `CellForRowAtIndexPath`. In `didSet` of the cell class, I can print "random text" just fine, however, for reasons unrelated to this question, I need to print "random text" inside of the lazy var. When I try to print it inside the lazy var, or even `awakeFromNib`, it gives me nil. I have an idea of why this is happening. I'm assuming the compiler runs certain code for a custom cell class before initializing any self properties. I'm wondering if there is a way to get around that.

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserCell
    cell.imageURL = "random text"
    return cell
}
```

Inside of the custom cell (UserCell)

```
class UserCell: UITableViewCell {
  var imageURL: String? {  
    didSet{
      print(imageURL)  //prints the imageURL
    }
}

 lazy var profileImageView: UIImageView = {

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    print(imageURL)   /////prints nil 
    return imageView
}()
```

Comment: since you are using a tableview, why don't you save all the `urls` inside of an `array of urls` then use it :)

Comment: @slimboy Your question and problem are completely different, first please update your question header.

Comment: Its happening because your `profileImageView` is a lazy initialised variable which will not be initialised until its required. I dont see any usage of `profileImageView` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. It wont exist until and unless its required or used. To check just log `profileImageView` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you will get the solution

Comment: @Dipen Panchasara , lazy var is inside UserCell, which gets activated everytime a cell is "dequeued" in cellForRow. Why would it print nil if it wasnt being activated ...

Comment: another thing your setter method isn't called on `init`, it only calls when you set value explicitly for `imageURL` as well, where is usage of `profileImageView` `UIImageView`? As you are not using it anywhere it won't be available(initialised).

Comment: I solved my problem, simply called a private func from didset instead of using lazy Var. Thank you though.